# compress .txt file on s3 location to .gz file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to compress a .txt-  file to .gz which is on S3 location and then upload it to a different S3 bucket. I have written following code but its not working as expected:

```
def upload_gzipped(bucket, key, fp, compressed_fp=None, content_type='text/plain'):

    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_fp, mode='wb') as gz:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fp, gz)
    compressed_fp.seek(0)
    print(compressed_fp)

    bucket.upload_fileobj(
        compressed_fp,
        key,
        {'ContentType': content_type, 'ContentEncoding': 'gzip'})

source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

response = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=file_key_name)
original = BytesIO(response['Body'].read())
original.seek(0)

upload_gzipped(source_bucket, file_key_name, original)
```

Can someone please help here, or any other approach to gzip the file on S3 location

Comment: What do you mean by "not working as expected"? What part works and what part does not work?

Comment: You're not passing in anything for `compressed_fp`, you should be seeing an exception in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you are writing an AWS Lambda function.

A simpler program flow would probably be:

- Download the file to `/tmp/` using `s3_client.download_file()`
- Gzip the file
- Upload the file to S3 using `s3.client_upload_file()`
- Delete the files in `/tmp/`

Also, please note that the AWS Lambda function might be invoked with multiple objects being passed via the `event`. However, your code is currently only processing the first record with `event['Records'][0]`. The program should loop through these records like this:

```py
for record in event['Records']:

    source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key_name = record['s3']['object']['key']
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the file into your /tmp folder, it might be better to read it into a buffer since the /tmp folder has limited memory.

```
buffer = BytesIO(file.get()["Body"].read())
```

For gzipping you can simply use something like this:

```
gzipped_content = gzip.compress(f_in.read())
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(gzipped_content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's a similar tutorial here for a Lambda function: https://medium.com/p/f7bccf0099c9